# Button inside GridView devExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView:

```
 @Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
       {
           settings.Name = "GridView";

           settings.KeyFieldName = "Id";
           settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectByRowClick = true;
           settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowFocusedRow = true;

           settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectSingleRowOnly = true;

           settings.ClientSideEvents.RowClick = "function(s, e){rowSelected(s, e)}";

           settings.Columns.Add("CodeClient");
           settings.Columns.Add("Nom");
           settings.Columns.Add("Prenom");
           settings.Columns.Add("DateNaissance");

       }).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

I want a Button inside this GridView.
Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: will you be needing `Editing` mode in future or just simple gridview to show data ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `button` inside `Gridview`. You can add a `custom column` with a `button` as follows:

**C# Code**

```
settings.Columns.Add(column => {
            column.FieldName = "Unbound";
            column.Caption = "Button";
            column.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.String;
            column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
            column.Width = Unit.Percentage(10);
            column.SetDataItemTemplateContent((c) => {
                htmlHelper.DevExpress().Button(b => {
                    b.Name = "Button" + c.KeyValue;
                    b.Text = "Test";
                    b.ClientSideEvents.Click = string.Format(@"function(s, e) {{ alert({0}); }}", c.KeyValue);
                }).GetHtml();
            });
        });
```

For more information you can go through the below links:-

Simple Button inside Gridview: **https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T161954**

Gridview button with Editing mode:-

**https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q499774**

Main thing for `Editing mode` will be the settings of it

```
settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
settings.CommandColumn.NewButton.Visible = true;
settings.CommandColumn.DeleteButton.Visible = true;
settings.CommandColumn.EditButton.Visible = true;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i want how to make the action of any button delete,add and update

Comment: you can do something like `settingsBtn.Add, .....,` Go through the link which I provided you, It has all those actions in details

Comment: i see him but i went not an action to controller i want to executea method javascript in the same view   ajax

Comment: it seems to be something different than what your question was about. I guess adding a button inside a gridview was your question. Now You should post a new question for _executing method via javascript_ which needs detail explanation of what exactly you want, what you tried and where you got stucked. Also have a look [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-server-side-methods-using-JavaScript-and-JQuery-in-ASP.Net.aspx) for reference

Answer (score 0):

You can add a funcionality to your new button with something like this(This is a example from the code of one of my applications). It have 3 different custom buttons:

```
//html
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grvResultados" runat="server" EnableCallBacks="false" EnableTheming="True"
                                                OnBeforeColumnSortingGrouping="grvResultados_BeforeColumnSortingGrouping" 
                                                OnPageIndexChanged="grvResultados_PageIndexChanged"
                                                 OnCustomColumnDisplayText="grvResultados_CustomColumnDisplayText"
                                                Styles-Cell-Wrap="False" Theme="MetropolisBlue" Width="100%">
                                                <SettingsBehavior ColumnResizeMode="Control" />
                                                <SettingsPager Mode="ShowPager" NumericButtonCount="10" PageSize="20" PageSizeItemSettings-Visible="true"
                                                    Visible="true">
                                                    <PageSizeItemSettings Visible="True">
                                                    </PageSizeItemSettings>
                                                </SettingsPager>
                                                <Settings ShowHeaderFilterButton="true" ShowFooter="True" ShowFilterRow="True" ShowFilterRowMenu="True"
                                                    ShowHorizontalScrollBar="false" EnableFilterControlPopupMenuScrolling="true" ShowFilterBar="Auto"
                                                    VerticalScrollBarMode="Auto" VerticalScrollBarStyle="Standard" />
                                                <Styles>
                                                    <Cell Wrap="False">
                                                    </Cell>
                                                </Styles>
                                            </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Here is the code .cs

```
//Code
 protected void grvResultados_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.FieldName.Contains("FECHA"))
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value.ToString()))
            {
                try
                {
                    e.DisplayText = ((DateTime)e.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                }
                catch
                {
                    e.DisplayText = e.Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            e.Column.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.DateTime;
        }
    }
 protected void grvResultados_BeforeColumnSortingGrouping(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewBeforeColumnGroupingSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MuestraResultados(0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mpPage.MuestraPopUp(GenerarError(this.Page.ToString(), ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString()), "ERROR");
        }
    }

    protected void grvResultados_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MuestraResultados(grvResultados.PageIndex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mpPage.MuestraPopUp(GenerarError(this.Page.ToString(), ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString()), "ERROR");
        }
    }
```